# ionic 6 : Modal Controller not scrolling

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I Have a ionic modal controller which is displayed on click of a button. For me the modal is not scrolling if the ion-item in the modal component is having dettails from an object array.
I am not able to see rest of the list whic is not displayed intially in the screen.

**Modal Controller**

```
    console.log('Called');

    this.modalController
      .create({
        component: CagesComponent,
        breakpoints: [0.75],
        initialBreakpoint: 0.75,
        showBackdrop: true,
        backdropDismiss: true,
      })
      .then((modalEl) => {
        modalEl.present();
        return modalEl.onDidDismiss();
      })
      .then((resultData) => {
        console.log(resultData.data, resultData.role);
        if (resultData.role === 'confirm') {
          this.form.get('cageNo').setValue(resultData.data);
        }
      });
  }
```

**cages.component.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item button (click)="onCageSelect(cage)" *ngFor="let cage of cages">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start" >
      <img [src]="cage.cageImg">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <div class="item-desc">
      <h4>{{cage.name}}({{cage.type}})</h4>
      <h6>{{cage.description}}</h6>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>
```

**cages.component.ts**

```
import { IonicModule, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Cage } from 'src/app/cage/cage.model';
import { CageService } from 'src/app/cage/cage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cages',
  templateUrl: './cages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cages.component.scss'],
})
export class CagesComponent implements OnInit {
  cages: Cage[] = [];
  constructor(
    public cageSrvc: CageService,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cageSrvc.getCages().subscribe((cages) => {
      this.cages = cages;
    });
  }

  onCageSelect(cage: Cage) {
    console.log(cage.name);
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(cage.name, 'confirm');
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Place all your contents inside ion-content.

```
<ion-content>
  <!-- Your contents-->
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ion-content didnt solve my problem, it didnt even show up my modal anymore.
What I did was wrapping all my content on a container with the following css:

```
.helper-container {
    height: 85vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Adust height to whatever value you choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the `--overflow` variable, which the ionic modal uses to set the `overflow` css property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
ion-modal ion-content {
--offset-top: unset !important;
--offset-bottom: unset !important;
overflow: auto !important;
}
```